# How to return a dynamically typed value from a function in a trait object in rust?

Tags: rust

I may not describe the problem clearly enough in the title, but here is an equivalent version of my code:

```rust
trait A {}

trait B {
    type C: A;
    fn foo(self) -> Self::C;
}

fn process(b: Box<dyn B<C = dyn A>>) -> Box<dyn A> {
    Box::new(b.foo())
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn A + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> tests/test.rs:9:16
  |
9 |     Box::new(b.foo())
  |                ^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn A + 'static)`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a trait that seems designed for static use (evidenced by the associated type and the `self` parameter), and you want to use it dynamically. There are some issues right now. For one, the type `C` is long-since erased by the time we get to runtime, so just because `T: B<C = Something>` does *not* mean `T: B<C = dyn A>`. Traits don't really work this way. The second problem is that pesky `self`. `self` (by value) is unsized on a trait object, so it can't be called on one.

All in all, if you have a `dyn B`, that's pretty much worthless, since too much has already been lost.

The good news is: You don't want a `dyn B`. Let's write *another* trait called `DynamicB` that erases the types and produces a `dyn`-friendly version of `foo`.

```
trait DynamicB {
    fn boxed_foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn A>;
}
```

This is basically the signature you want: rather than taking a `self` by value directly, it takes one in a box, which means `self` can be unsized and we can still call this function. Additionally, the result is a `Box<dyn A>`, not a specific type, so again, we can work with this dynamically.

But we want `DynamicB` to work with existing `B`'s. In fact, we really want it to *only* work with existing `B`'s. If someone directly implements `DynamicB` for their type, then they've probably done something wrong. Fortunately, we can write a blanket `impl` to take every `B` and produce a `DynamicB` instance.

```
impl<Item, T> DynamicB for T
where Item: A + 'static,
      T: B<C=Item> {
    fn boxed_foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn A> {
        Box::new(self.foo())
    }
}
```

There's some exciting stuff happening here. We require that the item type `C` satisfy `'static`, which means it can't store any references to temporary things (if it did, we can't guarantee the lifetimes, since we're doing all of this with `dyn`). Then we take `self: Box<Self>`, which is a [totally allowed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods) but seldom-used type for `self`. And we delegate to the underlying `self.foo()` inside.

Now your `process` is easy and works with any `B`, as intended.

```
fn process(b: Box<dyn DynamicB>) -> Box<dyn A> {
    b.boxed_foo()
}
```

Internally, what all of this is doing is requiring Rust to make a virtual function table for `boxed_foo` (a completely `dyn`-friendly method), rather than for the trait `B` (which had no object-safe methods).